# Adding an image into gallery on Android

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I am creating an app that launches an intent to open the system camera and take a picture to save it into the pictures directory.

I am doing it as follows

```
private void captureImage(){

        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "MyApp";

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation);

        photoUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
        startActivityForResult(captureIntent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_CODE);
    }
```

The above code works fine on devices running Android 10. If it is run on a device running any version lower than Android 10 (API 29), then getContentResolver().insert() returns null.

Looking into it, I see it is failing with the error that "relative_path" column does not exist. Is this because MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH was added in API Level 29? If so, how to do it on older devices running older versions like Android Pie and Android Oreo?

Comment: There was the .DATA column for an absolute path. But did you try without .RELATIVE_PATH?

Comment: You can just save your file using File class and/or FileOutputStream and then let it be scanned by the media scanner.